# How to do a not stretchable textures in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to do a sand. I’ve got a texture, but it’s stretching over the entire mesh. How to make it not stretchable, but able to repeat itself over the mesh?

I was looking for answer for a long time, but didn’t find anything!

Comment: You need to change the tiling settings in the material. For sprites set the wrap mode to repeat.

Comment: Also depends on the UV mapping of your model / used shader

Comment: Look for Triplanar Shader Graph